# Существование файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть папка А, которая включает папки А1, А2 ит.д., папка А1, А2, А3 и т.д включают папки 1, 2, 3 и т.д. Как проверять папки 1, 2, 3 и т.д. на существования файла, например file.txt. С одной папкой и с подпапкой просто. А тут уже 3 уровня. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: `os.walk` умеет ходить по всем вложенным каталогам

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать модуль [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html). С помощью `recursive=True` и `**` в пути, можно заставить функцию искать во всех подпапках. В вашем случае код может быть примерно таким:

```
import glob


files = glob.glob('A/**/file.txt', recursive=True)
print(files)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

path = 'D:\PyQt5'
fileName = 'dyld.pyc'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    if fileName in files:
        print("{}\{}".format(root,fileName))


D:\PyQt5\mp3\lib\ctypes\macholib\dyld.pyc
D:\PyQt5\screenshot\lib\ctypes\macholib\dyld.pyc
```